# Magento 2 Custom Attribute Multi select without specific options

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

What can be the solution on Magento 2 to have a Customer Attribute multi-select where the customer can save custom values on the fly?

For example:

- Add your five favorite movies

Is there some JSON attribute save solution for Magento 2?

Thanks in advance..!